# How do i generate more than 1 pdfs on click of a button

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am creating a component for teachers where in teacher can generate pdf for all the students who have completed the course.
Checking all the students and pdfs should be generated and saved on disk. After which a download link is provided to download the zip of all the pdfs generated. This is what i want to achieve. I am using fpdf for generating pdf.
Any suggestions ?

Below is the form that is posted and students id-

```
    <form
        action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mentor&view=download_certificate&cid=' . $cid . '&Itemid=529') ?>"
        name="download_certificate" method="post" id="download_certificate">
        <table class="adminlist" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
               style="table-layout: fixed" id="content">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="nowrap" style="width: 35px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectall" id="selectall">
                </th>
                <th class="nowrap" align="center">
                    <?php echo JText::_('COM_MENTOR_USER_NAME'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="nowrap" style="width: 140px">
                    <?php echo JText::_('COM_MENTOR_COURSE_STATUS'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="nowrap" style="width: 140px">
                    <?php echo JText::_('COM_MENTOR_ENROLLMENT_DATE'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="nowrap" style="width: 140px">
                    <?php echo JText::_('COM_MENTOR_ACTIVITY'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="nowrap" style="width: 50px">
                    <?php echo JText::_('COM_MENTOR_SCORE'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="nowrap" style="width: 50px">
                    <?php echo JText::_('COM_MENTOR_RESULT'); ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            //echo '<pre>';print_r($this->mentor_details); die;
            foreach ($this->mentor_details as $students) {
                $cid = $this->mentor_details['cid'];
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($students['students'] as $student) {
                    $userid = $student['id'];
//                echo '<pre>';
//                print_r($student);
//                die;
                    ?>
                    <tr class="status" id="<?php echo $userid ?>">
                        <td align="center">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $userid ?>" name="check[]" class="checkbox1"
                                   value="<?php echo $userid ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mentor&view=grader&cid=' . $cid . '&uid='
                                . $userid . $itemid) ?>">
                                <?php echo $student['username']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <!--                    <td>
                        <?php// echo $student['email']; ?>
                    </td> -->
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php
                            $incomplete = $completed = $not_started = 0;
                            for ($k = 0; $k < count($student['elements']); $k++) {
                                foreach ($student['elements'] as $elements) {
                                    if ($elements['userid'] == $userid) {
//                                    echo '<pre>';print_r($elements); die;
                                        if ($elements['element']['cmi.core.lesson_status'] == 'incomplete') {
                                            $incomplete++;
                                        } else {
                                            $completed++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if ($incomplete == 0 && $completed == 0) {
                                echo 'Not yet started';
                            } else {
                                if ($completed == count($student['elements'])) {
                                    echo 'Completed';
                                } else {
                                    echo 'Incomplete';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($student['timestart'])) {
                                $date = date('d-m-Y H:i', $student['timestart']);
                                echo $date;
                            } else {
                                echo "Not yet started";
                            } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($student['activity']['lasttime']) && (!empty($student['activity']['starttime']))) {
                                $start_date = date('d-m-Y H:i', $student['activity']['starttime']);
                                $last_date = date('d-m-Y H:i', $student['activity']['lasttime']);
                                echo $start_date . '<br/>' . $last_date;
                            } else {
                                echo "-";
                            } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php
                            $grades = $student['grades'];
                            $total_grade = array();
                            $j = 0;
                            //for ($j = 0; $j < count($grades); $j++) {
                            //    $total_grade[$j] = $grades[$j]['finalgrade'];
                            //}
                            //print_r($total_grade);die;
                            if (!empty($grades)) {
                                //echo number_format(array_sum($total_grade), 2);
                                $total_grade[$j] = $grades[$j]['finalgrade'];
                                echo number_format($total_grade[$j], 2);
                            } else {
                                echo '-';
                            }
                            //echo '<pre>';
                            //print_r($student['grades']);
                            //die;
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <?php
                            //echo '<pre>';print_r($student);die;
                            if (!empty($student['scores'])) {
                                if (isset($grades[$j]['feedbacktext'])) {
                                    echo $grades[$j]['feedbacktext'];
                                } else {
                                    echo '-';
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo '-';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++;
                }
            } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
<script>
function checked_value() {
        var checkedValue = [];
        var $len = $(".checkbox1:checked").length;

        if ($len == 0) {
            alert('Please select user');
        }
//        else if ($len > 1) {
//            alert('Please select a single user only.');
//        }
        else {
            $(".checkbox1").each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.is(":checked")) {
                    checkedValue.push($this.attr("id"));
                }
            });

            $("#download_certificate").submit();
    </script>
```

On Clicking image tag, form is submitted with the students id and I am getting students data, his name, grades, course,

```
<img src="/components/com_mentor/images/certificate_blue.png" class="certificate-ico right"
             title="Download Certificate" onclick="checked_value();"/>
```

After this processing, page is redirected to pdf.php page

```
require_once('/wamp/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lms/lib/fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF(); $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(50, 60, 100); $pdf->AddPage('L');
$pdf->SetDisplayMode(real, 'default'); $pdf->SetXY(10, 60);
$pdf->SetFontSize(12);
$pdf->Write(5, 'Dear Ms.XYX');
$filename = "test.pdf";
$dir = "/assets/";
$pdf->Output($dir . $filename, 'F');
```

Comment: Please post relevant code sections. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: right now wen i click button for pdf only 1 is generated and saved. But I want for say 10 students. Below is the code I used to generate pdf:



`require_once('/wamp/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lms/lib/fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(50, 60, 100);
$pdf->AddPage('L');
$pdf->SetDisplayMode(real, 'default');
$pdf->SetXY(10, 60);
$pdf->SetFontSize(12);
$pdf->Write(5, 'Dear Ms.XYX');
$filename = "test.pdf";
$dir = "/assets/"; 
$pdf->Output($dir . $filename, 'F');`

Comment: Your code above doesn't show much beyond a basic template for PDF generation. Have you written any code that pulls information on specific students for that teacher? If not, I would recommend starting there first.

Comment: yes.. I am getting all the students assigned under a teacher and all the required data.. I am just stuck on the pdf part which is generating pdfs for all the students under a teacher who have completed their course

Comment: Well, `foreach` from PHP could come in handy. If you want 10 identical PDFs, just loop the part with `$pdf->Output()` over a changing filename.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help.. Solved my question.
Looped through the pdf function for n no. of users.